# iframe contentWindow not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<script>
function getDef() {
    document.getElementById("defCanvas").innerHTML=document.getElementById("invisibleDefFrame").contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("def-content")[0].innerText;
}
</script>
<button onclick="getDef();">Get Definition</button>
<iframe style="display:none;" id="invisibleDefFrame" src="http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amalgamation?s=t"></iframe>
<p id="defCanvas"></p>
```

This is my code for a program that should return the definition of a word, but instead does nothing. What should I do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you expand on "does nothing"? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the iframe this way!

You will get an **Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin**

Read this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame#answer-25098153)

Answer (score 1):

Because of cross-domain security, I suspect that you are not able to access the HTML of that iframe from within your own page via Javascript.

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459187/iframe-cross-domain-access).

I believe that the only way to do what you are trying to do - scrape results from another website and display them on your own - is to make the request via your own web server, parse the results and present it to the user.